# np.ma.argmax on masked array of unsigned integer dtype returns wrong result in numpy 1.11.0

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, masked-array

I stumbled over a strange fact concerning masked unsigned integer arrays and [`np.ma.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.argmax.html#numpy-ma-argmax).

Consider the following array:

```
>>> marr = np.ma.array(np.array([[2,2,2], [3,3,3], [1,1,1]]), mask=False, dtype=np.uint16)
>>> marr
masked_array(data =
 [[2 2 2]
 [3 3 3]
 [1 1 1]],
             mask =
 [[False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

If I use [`np.ma.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.argmax.html#numpy-ma-argmax) the result is what I expected:

```
>>> print(np.ma.argmax(marr, axis=0))
[1 1 1]
```

If I now mask the last row the result is wrong:

```
>>> marr.mask[2] = True
>>> marr
masked_array(data =
 [[2 2 2]
 [3 3 3]
 [-- -- --]],
             mask =
 [[False False False]
 [False False False]
 [ True  True  True]],
       fill_value = 999999)
>>> print(np.ma.argmax(marr, axis=0))
[2 2 2]   # why?
```

It now thinks the masked row is the maximum? I even changed the `fill_value` to 0 but the result stays the same: It still thinks the masked row is the maximum. It seems like this only affects unsigned integer arrays.

However [`np.ma.MaskedArray.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.MaskedArray.argmax.html#numpy.ma.MaskedArray.argmax) and [`np.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) return the correct result:

```
>>> print(marr.argmax(axis=0))
[1 1 1]
>>> print(np.argmax(marr, axis=0))
[1 1 1]
```

Why is the `np.ma.argmax` not doing the correct thing here? As far as I can see it is defined as [the method itself](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/59a7b250d4076d58c8b48bdf3800f2b1eac41e1b/numpy/ma/core.py#L6463).

Comment: Check the history of that `argmax` definition.  There may have been a recent change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code for `np.ma.argmax` (via `ipython` `??` magic) (version '1.11.0')

```
Definition:  np.ma.argmax(a, axis=None, fill_value=None)
Source:
def argmax(a, axis=None, fill_value=None):
    "Function version of the eponymous method."
    if fill_value is None:
        fill_value = default_fill_value(a)
        try:
            fill_value = -fill_value
        except:
            pass
    d = filled(a, fill_value)
    return d.argmax(axis=axis)
```

and for the method:

```
def argmax(self, axis=None, fill_value=None, out=None):
    if fill_value is None:
        fill_value = maximum_fill_value(self._data)
    d = self.filled(fill_value).view(ndarray)
    return d.argmax(axis, out=out)
```

The function uses a different fill value

```
In [180]: np.ma.maximum_fill_value(marr)
Out[180]: 0

In [181]: np.ma.maximum_fill_value(marr.astype(int))
Out[181]: -2147483648

In [182]: np.ma.default_fill_value(marr)
Out[182]: array(999999)

In [183]: -np.ma.default_fill_value(marr)
Out[183]: -999999

In [184]: np.ma.filled(marr,-np.ma.default_fill_value(marr))
Out[184]: 
array([[    2,     2,     2],
       [    3,     3,     3],
       [48577, 48577, 48577]], dtype=uint16)

In [186]: np.ma.filled(marr,np.ma.maximum_fill_value(marr))
Out[186]: 
array([[2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint16)
```

It's a bug in my version.   There was a change in Feb, replacing the `argmax` (and argmin) with the method (`argmax = _frommethod('argmax')`).

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/36f76ea2e6e91062df12d3a46ccaed7822bc82f2

So that correction isn't in my distribution - an presumably not yours.

So for now stick with method, or provide your own correct fill_value.

```
In [187]: np.ma.argmax(marr,axis=0,fill_value=0)
Out[187]: array([1, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Good hint about digging through the history. Weird that the function (not method) wants to use the negative fill_value though. :-) Thanks!

Comment: It works for signed types.  I think it's just a case of progressive refinement.  `unint` is not used nearly as much as `int`, so falls through the cracks.

Answer (score 0):

As @hpaulj already hinted it was a Bug in numpy version 1.11.0. In newer numpy versions (for example 1.11.3) the Bug has been fixed:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__version__
'1.11.3'
>>> marr = np.ma.array(np.array([[2,2,2], [3,3,3], [1,1,1]]), mask=False, dtype=np.uint16)
>>> marr.mask[2] = True
>>> print(np.ma.argmax(marr, axis=0))
[1 1 1]
```